# Entity Framework Abstract Class with Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am working on a small architecture change to an existing application using Entity Framework and trying to get a base class to have a navigation property, but for some reason EF keeps trying to add it twice and I'm not entirely sure why.

The class structure is setup as:

```
public abstract class PurchaseOrderItem
{
     //foreign key reference
     public long PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }

     //parent entity
     public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderProduct : PurchaseOrderItem
{
    //general properties that a PurchaseOrderItem doesn't have
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    //navigation property to items, which will include purchase order products
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The navigation property on `PurchaseOrderItem` is setup as:

`HasRequired(p => p.PurchaseOrder).WithMany(p => p.Items).HasForeignKey(p => p.PurchaseOrderId);`

The database structure is a one-to-one relationship, as is the actual configuration setup inside `PurchaseOrderProduct`. When the SQL query is run by Entity Framework, it includes the default `PurchaseOrderId` key as expected on the `PurchaseOrderItem`, but then it also includes `PurchaseOrder_Id` targeting the `PurchaseOrderProduct` table, which fails because it doesn't exist since that's associated with the base class and intentionally not on the inherited classes.

Has anyone else run into this before and/or have any suggestions? It seems pretty straightforward.

** UPDATE **

I started playing with this further, by creating new classes that mimic this structure called `TestPOItem` and `TestPOItemProduct`, but that lead to another issue where it was saying `TestPOItem` and `PurchaseOrderItem` could not be configured to map to `PurchaseOrderItems` (a table that doesn't exist and isn't configured anyway) which further lent itself to EF doing something very strange.

Even stranger, when I added `PurchaseOrderProduct_Id` as a property on the POCO `PurchaseOrderProduct` entity and marked it as `Ignore(p => p.PurchaseOrderProduct_Id)`, it still added it and where it got incredibly weird is when I added the foreign key references from `PurchaseOrderItem` to `PurchaseOrderProduct` and removed them from `PurchaseOrderItem`, I re-ran the unit test and it was suddenly looking for `PurchaseOrder_Id2` which definitely exists nowhere.

Unfortunately, I think I have to chalk this up to EF getting itself tripped up somewhere internally and come up with an alternate solution. We use plenty of one-to-one relationships in this system, but never have any of the abstract base classes had a navigation property on them. It's always the inherited class that has those specified.

Comment: It's already up there - it just has a few generic properties (strings and ints) that are standard. No navigation properties or anything like that on it. Very basic POCO class.